# Custom templates based custom url structure in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm working on a website that includes a section for Barbers, and I want to achieve the following URL structure:

```
Barbers {domain.com/barbers This page will have 2 section, 1 section will list Barber Organizations and another section will have list of states which have barbers}/
├── Individual Organization Page {domain.com/<<organization-name>> this page will display overview of the organization, contact details and have further 3 parts}/
│   ├── Branches {domain.com/<<organization-name>>/branches this page will again display list of states related to the selected organization}/
│   │   └── Individual State  {domain.com/<<organization-name>>/branches/<<state>> this page will again display list of cities, in the states selected previously, related to the selected organization}/
│   │       └── Individual City {domain.com/<<organization-name>>/branches/<<state>>/<<city>> this page will again display all branches, in the city selected previously, related to the selected organization}
│   ├── Barbers related to the selected organization {domain.com/<<company-name>>/barbers} this will again list all the states which have barbers related to the selected organization/
│   │   └── Individual State  {domain.com/<<organization-name>>/barbers/<<state>> this page will again display list of cities, in the state selected previously, related to the selected organization}/
│   │       └── Individual City {domain.com/<<organization-name>>/barbers/<<state>>/<<city>> this page will again display all barbers, in the city selected previously, related to the selected organization}
│   └── Super Barbers related to the selected company {domain.com/<<organization-name>>/super-barbers this will display list of Super Barbers for the selected organization}
└── Individual State  {domain.com/barbers/<<state>> this will display list of cities which have barbers, irrespective of any organization}/
    └── Individual City {domain.com/barbers/<<state>>/<<city>> this will display list of barbers in the selected City, irrespective of any organization}
```

Please refer this image [link](https://imgur.com/AVldhxc) for a flow chart for better understand and visualization.

I plan to create custom post types for the elements mentioned above and link them using ACF Relationship fields or the P2P plugin.

1. Barbers
2. Organizations
3. States
4. Cities
5. Super Barbers
6. Branches

Here are my questions:

1. What templates do I need to create to achieve this URL structure?
2. Is there a way to register a layout type based on the URL structure?
3. How efficient and SEO-friendly can this approach be?

Please note that, apart from organizations, nothing else will have a single.php template; everything else will be in archive or listing format related to the parameters mentioned.

Thank you in advance.